# Glabal variable not dependant on session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to have a global variable that is not session dependent?
I want to have a list of all the SignalR connections and the user ID form the db.

So far I have something like this :

```
public class SignalRUsersService : ISignalRUsersService
{
    private int userId;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public List<ConnectedSignalR> SignalRUsers;
    public SignalRUsersService( IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
        try
        {
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(_accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("uID"));
        }
        catch
        {
            userId = 0;
        }
        SignalRUsers = new List<ConnectedSignalR>();
    }


    public void AddSignalRUser(string ConnID)
    {
        SignalRUsers.Add(new ConnectedSignalR()
        {
            ConnID = ConnID,
            UserID = userId
        });
    }
    public void RemoveSignalRUser(string ConnID)
    {
        var usr = SignalRUsers.Where(a => a.ConnID == ConnID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (usr != null)
        {
            SignalRUsers.Remove(usr);
        }
    }
    public List<ConnectedSignalR> GetSignalRUsers()
    {
        return SignalRUsers;
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I use the interface it seems it's re-initializing my SignalRUsers list. And even if I push the data in the list I find it null when I need it.

Is SignalRUsers session dependent? Or is it just a matter of not using the interface in a right way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR hubs are transient, which means a new instance is created when a method call is received from a client (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server).

You are probably injecting this service into a hub class, which means you can use dependency injection configuration to control the lifetime of your service class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISignalRUsersService, SignalRUsersService>();
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks I had this as `services.AddTransient<ISignalRUsersService, SignalRUsersService>();`